# Parse Daunting JSON: PHP

Tags: php, json

So I have a huge JSON chunk of data that I need to parse. It has been converted to a PHP array with `json_decode`. Below is one element of the `data` object in the PHP array. There are hundreds of these elements, below is just one:

```
'{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3215,
            "user_id": {
                "id": 99106,
                "name": "Rusty shackleford",
                "email": "Rusty.shackleford@company.com",
                "has_pic": true,
                "pic_hash": "someHash",
                "active_flag": true,
                "value": 99106
            },
            "person_id": {
                "name": "rusty shackleford",
                "email": [
                    {
                        "label": "Work",
                        "value": "rusty shackleford@email.com",
                        "primary": true
                    }
                ],
                "phone": [
                    {
                        "label": "Fax",
                        "value": "666-666-6666",
                        "primary": false
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "main",
                        "value": "666-666-6666",
                        "primary": false
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "main",
                        "value": "666-666-6666",
                        "primary": true
                    }
                ],
                "value": 666
            },
            "org_id": {
                "name": "shackleford, Inc.",
                "people_count": 23,
                "cc_email": "rusty@6theShack.com",
                "value": 1013
            },
            "stage_id": 8,
            "title": "rusty\'s Projects",
            "value": 0,
            "currency": "USD",
            "add_time": "2013-01-15 00:00:00",
            "update_time": "2015-07-07 14:28:15",
            "stage_change_time": "2013-10-30 14:43:09",
            "active": true,
            "deleted": false,
            "status": "open",
            "next_activity_date": "2015-07-07",
            "next_activity_time": null,
            "next_activity_id": 3771,
            "last_activity_id": 252,
            "last_activity_date": "2013-11-16",
            "lost_reason": null,
            "visible_to": "3",
            "close_time": null,
            "pipeline_id": 1,
            "won_time": null,
            "lost_time": null,
            "products_count": null,
            "files_count": null,
            "notes_count": 21,
            "followers_count": 1,
            "email_messages_count": null,
            "activities_count": 2,
            "done_activities_count": 1,
            "undone_activities_count": 1,
            "reference_activities_count": 0,
            "participants_count": 1,
            "b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d": "",
            "17a14a9da9815451ff5ffc669d407e8b0376b06b": 4616,
            "3eedd4fd08f44a72d911dc4934a6916f3b31911b": "",
            "52ede287f6c55eb6b12821ca24f74098779abdce": "",
            "13916ba291ab595f27aefbff8b6c43a3fb467b72": "shackleford LLP",
            "6330684838740625ea6a7d260f102a1961b2fae1": "shackleford, Inc.",
            "ded823307920bf70cea49c45684148fd295e179a": "",
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_lat": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_long": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_subpremise": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_street_number": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_route": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_sublocality": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_locality": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_admin_area_level_1": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_admin_area_level_2": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_country": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_postal_code": null,
            "ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_formatted_address": null,
            "09358ea07e1a1007d24bc068c723bf1f79e8359d": null,
            "expected_close_date": null,
            "7cce64c3abb5f28a260bc9d6719a43367bae5dfe": null,
            "stage_order_nr": 10,
            "person_name": "shackleford",
            "org_name": "shackleford, Inc.",
            "next_activity_subject": "pocket Sand!",
            "next_activity_type": "task",
            "next_activity_duration": "00:00:00",
            "next_activity_note": "",
            "formatted_value": "$0",
            "weighted_value": 0,
            "formatted_weighted_value": "$0",
            "rotten_time": null,
            "owner_name": "Rusty shackleford",
            "cc_email": "rusty+stuff3215@shackleford.com",
            "org_hidden": false,
            "person_hidden": false
        }
    ]
}'
```

Below is some of my code so far:

```
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
//$ksortResult = ksort($response['data']);
foreach($response as $field){
    echo $field;
}
```

If anyone can help me step through the json object with arrays, I'd greatly appreciate it. Also, I'm trying to sort the data based on keys before I step through it.

The desired output would be like the one below:

```
id|user_id|person_id|org_id|stage_id|title|value|currency|add_time|update_time|stage_change_time|active|deleted|status|next_activity_date|next_activity_time|next_activity_id|last_activity_id|last_activity_date|lost_reason|visible_to|close_time|pipeline_id|won_time|lost_time|products_count|files_count|notes_count|followers_count|email_messages_count|activities_count|done_activities_count|undone_activities_count|reference_activities_count|participants_count|b98336b40c8420dc2f1401d6451b1b47198eee6d|_17a14a9da9815451ff5ffc669d407e8b0376b06b|_3eedd4fd08f44a72d911dc4934a6916f3b31911b|_52ede287f6c55eb6b12821ca24f74098779abdce|_13916ba291ab595f27aefbff8b6c43a3fb467b72|_6330684838740625ea6a7d260f102a1961b2fae1|ded823307920bf70cea49c45684148fd295e179a ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_lat    ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_long|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_subpremise|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_street_number|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_route|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_sublocality|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_locality|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_admin_area_level_1|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_admin_area_level_2|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_country|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_postal_code|ed35f69413af7156058d1081321e7bb227577eef_formatted_address|_09358ea07e1a1007d24bc068c723bf1f79e8359d|expected_close_date|_7cce64c3abb5f28a260bc9d6719a43367bae5dfe|stage_order_nr|person_name  org_name|next_activity_subject|next_activity_type|next_activity_duration|next_activity_note|formatted_value|weighted_value|formatted_weighted_value|rotten_time owner_name|cc_email|org_hidden|person_hidden|user_name|user_email|person_phone_1    person_phone_2|person_phone_3|org_people_count
3215|99106|666|1013|8|rusty's Projects|0|USD|1/15/2013 0:00|7/7/2015 14:28|10/30/2013 14:43|TRUE|FALSE|open|7/7/2015|null|3771|252|11/16/2013|null|3|null|1|null|null|null|null|21|1|null|2|1|1|0|1||4616|||shackleford LLP|shackleford,Inc.||null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|null|10|shackleford|shackleford, Inc.|pocket Sand!|task|0:00:00||$0|0|$0|0:00:00|Rusty shackleford|rusty+stuff3215@shackleford.com|FALSE|FALSE|Rusty shackleford|Rusty.shackleford@company.com|666-666-6666|666-666-6666|666-666-6666|23
```

Comment: you're **NOT** stepping through a json object. you're dealing with a PHP array, and just because it was originally json doesn't make it magically different from a "normal" php array... `var_dump($response)` and dig down.

Comment: @MarcB I edited the question, so it will be called PHP array.

Comment: using the above JSON, can you give us what you want the outcome to be?

Comment: @iam-decoder Yes, this may take a few minutes tho.

Comment: no worries, just need some direction.

Comment: http://array.include-once.org/ for inspecting the JSON dump and how to access it as PHP array/object.

Comment: You might want to pay attention to the very important fact that `ksort` takes an array **by-reference** and returns a boolean `true` or `false`. In other words, your code makes no sense and does nothing useful. Furthermore, you should note that sort by keys in this array (in this particular example) would be entirely and utterly pointless since the array — `$response['data']` — would already be sorted by keys based on this JSON string.

Comment: @pHorseSpec are you just trying to get all the array keys to be sorted alphabetically?

Comment: @iam-decoder I could go without sorting the data. I'm just trying to write it to it's proper column header, or key, when written to an external csv file. At one point, I thought sorting the keys would be a good idea, because my json data, or php array, isn't in the same order in all elements.

Comment: I ended up not using `ksort` and I mapped each column's data to a specific value in the json data object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly you want to flatten the json structure? If that's the case, take a look at look at array_walk_recursive:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Which would look something like this:

```
$newArray = [];

array_walk_recursive( $formerlyJsonArray, 
    function($value, $key) use (&$newArray) {
        $newArray[$key] = $value; 
});
```

Or take a look at array_reduce:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php